# Why is nginx hanging when reverse proxying an image with content-length: 0?

Tags: nginx

I'm encountering an issue that appears to be a result of an upstream server returning an invalid Content-Length header for an image. The image exists on the upstream server, but it inexplicably returns Content-Length: 0 in the HTTP headers. Unfortunately, it seems as if this is tripping up NGINX and causing requests for that image to hang. I've been able to run the same test using a different proxy middleware (node-http-proxy) and it has no problem with dealing with the incorrect Content-Length header - the image is returned as expected.

Does anyone know whether it's possible to get NGINX to work around this? Can I tell it to ignore the Content-Length header?

Many thanks!